# Install in-house iOS App Wirelessly with manifest.plist without user intervention

Tags: ios, in-house-distribution

I am following documentation for distributing the in-house app

http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/#app43ad871e

I am able to install the app but I wonder is it possible to stop the pop up asking user's permission.

I need this feature because we are a digital signage company so we manage/configure/schedule content for thousands of iPads remotely and there is no user to operate the device.

Comment: You should look into Apple's MDM for this http://www.apple.com/ipad/business/it-center/deployment-mdm.html

Answer (score 0):

We've been looking for something similar and discovered https://meraki.cisco.com. Its a free MDM option (they build hardware with some more advanced features) but the silent remote install is definitely possible within the free options.